# DataFrame with 3 columns to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following `DataFrame` with 3 columns

```
my_label               product             count

175                    '409'                41
175                    '407'                 8
175                    '0.5L'                4
175                    '1.5L'                4
177                    'SCHWEPPES'           6
177                    'TONIC 1L'            4
```

How I can transform it to dictionary of dictionaries:

```
{175: {'409':41,'407':8, '0.5L':4, '1.5L':4}, 
 177: {'SCHWEPPES':6, 'TONIC 1L':4}}
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: 1. What have you already tried? 2. Is it guaranteed that `my_label` and `product` pairs are unique?

Comment: @DeepSpace the combination is unique

Comment: Did you saw my answer for your earlier question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straightforward way is to groupby `my_label` then iterate over the resulting rows, grabbing the values you need:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   my_label      product  count
0       175        '409'     41
1       175        '407'      8
2       175       '0.5L'      4
3       175       '1.5L'      4
4       177  'SCHWEPPES'      6
5       177   'TONIC-1L'      4

In [8]: {k:{t.product:t.count for t in g.itertuples(index=False)} for k,g in df.groupby('my_label')}
Out[8]:
{175: {"'0.5L'": 4, "'1.5L'": 4, "'407'": 8, "'409'": 41},
 177: {"'SCHWEPPES'": 6, "'TONIC-1L'": 4}}
```

Here's that nested dictionary-comprehension written a bit more neatly:

```
{k:{t.product:t.count for t in g.itertuples(index=False)} 
    for k,g in df.groupby('my_label')}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one ugly one-liner:

```
In [83]: df.set_index('my_label') \
           .groupby(level=0) \
           .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('product').T.to_dict('r')[0]) \
           .to_dict()
Out[83]:
{175: {'0.5L': 4, '1.5L': 4, '407': 8, '409': 41},
 177: {'SCHWEPPES': 6, 'TONIC 1L': 4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[My original answer for you previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718178/dataframe-columns-to-key-value-dictionary-pair/46718295#46718295)

```
df.groupby(level='Id').apply(lambda x : x.set_index('product').T.to_dict(orient='records')).apply(lambda x : x[0]).to_dict()
Out[137]: 
{175: {"'0.5L'": 4, "'1.5L'": 4, "'407'": 8, "'409'": 41},
 177: {"'SCHWEPPES'": 6, "'TONIC1L'": 4}}
```